# Google charts HTML right to left issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization, right-to-left

I'm getting a weird bug while using Google Charts with dir="rtl" tag in the html for right to left webpages.

What happens is the page gets a massive space and scrolls left for no reason. Happens on my Chrome and Safari.

```
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
```

This is the easiest way to reproduce the bug on jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/t4ve0kkf/

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');

  data.addRows([
    [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1],
    [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2],
    [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3],
    [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4],
    [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5],
    [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6],
    [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7],
    [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8],
    [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9],
    [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10],
  ]);

    var options = {
    title: 'Motivation Level Throughout the Day',
    hAxis: {
    title: 'Time of Day',
    format: 'h:mm a',
    viewWindow: {
    min: [7, 30, 0],
               max: [17, 30, 0]
               }
               },
               vAxis: {
               title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)'
               }
               };

               var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
               document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</html>
```

I've also tried adding lang and dir to the chart div while keeping the rtl tag in the main html but didn't work

```
<div id="chart_div" lang="en" dir="ltr"> </div>
```

Comment: Try setting like this:  <div dir="rtl" id="chart_div"></div>

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh OP wants to have it in the root since the page is clearly a rtl language (Arabic)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan is correct, the page is a rtl Arabic page and just need to add a Google Chart to it.

Comment: The rtl is making it render oriented from the right side of the page, instead of the left. One thing you can do is give the div `style="float:left;"` though you would have to do some more legwork to adjust the width https://jsfiddle.net/t4ve0kkf/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking rendered HTML with page inspectors it appears that this part of the HTML causes the issue:

```
<div aria-label="Данные диаграммы в виде таблицы." style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: auto; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;">/* ... */</div>
```

So basically "hiding" ARIA element with `left: -10000px` is not compatible with rtl documents, since clearly it's going to add this huge gap due to negative left.

One way to fix it is to force this aria-lable to render with `left: auto` and move it far to the top instead:

```
html[dir="rtl"] svg + [aria-label] {
    top: -1000px !important;
    left: auto !important;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/57oe0ktz/

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks this worked perfectly. Not sure of any side-effects yet but so far looks as clear as a blue sky. I'm not sure how you found the aria-label cause I looked around with Chrome dev tools and didn't find it.

Comment: I suppose there should be no side-effects. There would be if you were to hide this aria-lebel with `display: none`, then it would also fix gap, but then screen-readers would fail to find accessibility content. Moving it to the negative top is not different from left: -100000.

Comment: thanks alot :) this helped me after a long day of debugging